spring angular pagination problem sorting outputed data
i have a spring boot angular application already implemented ,i'm trying to implement a pagination within the project ,eveyrthing works fine except the fact that the data fetched to client side is not sorted properly ,for example i find data starts with id number 10 ,11 .. then unexpectedly jumps to id number 15 ,i also find id number 1 in page number 5 and so on ..
you can find images below illustrating my problem (sorry for deleting the rows ,it's confidential plus we only have interest in the id column)
problem 2 : let's say i updated the record of id =10, after saving the updates ,the record with id 10 dissapears from page 1 and get displayed in page 4 (for example)
i really can't find a solution to this strange behavior
you can find also the project's code : spring boot :
Repository:
public interface ServiceTypeRepository extends JpaRepository<ServiceType, Long>

    Page<ServiceType> findAll(Pageable pageable);
}

Service:
public Page<ServiceType> getServiceTypes(Pageable pageable) {
        return ServiceTypeRepository.findAll(pageable);

Resource(controller):
@ApiResponse(responseCode = "401", description = "Unauthorized")
    @GetMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @PreAuthorize(AccessRightConstants.SERVICETYPE_READ_PERMISSION)
    public ResponseEntity<List<ServiceTypeV2DTO>> get(Pageable pageable) { //  @RequestParam(defaultValue = "1") int page @RequestParam(defaultValue = "10") int size
        log.debug("REST request to get service types");
        // Pageable paging = PageRequest.of(page, size);
        Page<ServiceType> serviceTypes = ServiceTypeServiceV2.getServiceTypes(pageable);

        List<ServiceTypeV2DTO> serviceTypeV2DTOS = serviceTypes.stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(ServiceType::getNumericId))
                .map(DtoFactory::createServiceTypeV2DTO)
                .toList();

        return ResponseEntity.ok(serviceTypeV2DTOS);


angular app : (angular 17) :
Service methods :
 GetAll(params): Observable<any[]>{
        return this.httpClient.get<any[]>(`${this.SERVICE_TYPE_CONTEXT}`,{params});
    }

Update(ServiceDtoToSave : any): Observable<ServiceType>{
    let servTypeServiceDtoToSave: ServiceType = this.mapObjectToSave(ServiceDtoToSave);
        return this.httpClient.put<ServiceType>(`${(this.SERVICE_TYPE_CONTEXT)}` , servTypeServiceDtoToSave);
}

mapObjectToSave(serviceTypeDto: any): ServiceType{
        let ServiceDtoToSave : ServiceType = new ServiceType();
        serviceTypeDto.value? ServiceDtoToSave.value = serviceTypeDto.value:null;
        ServiceDtoToSave.name = serviceTypeDto.name;
        ServiceDtoToSave.minF = serviceTypeDto.minFwVersion;
         ServiceDtoToSave.compat = serviceTypeDto.compat;
        ServiceDtoToSave.compat2 = serviceTypeDto.compat2;
        ServiceDtoToSave.compat3 = serviceTypeDto.compat3;
        ServiceDtoToSave.compat4= serviceTypeDto.compat4;
        ServiceDtoToSave.attributesService = [];
        ServiceDtoToSave?.attributesService.forEach(attribute=> {
            ServiceDtoToSave.attributesService.push({
                name : attribute.name,
                value : attribute.value
            })});

        return ServiceDtoToSave;
    }



component.ts:


//declaration

   page: number = 1;
    pageSize: number = 26;
    name = '';



   totalItems: number = 256;

    serviceTypeForm: FormGroup
    editmode = false;
    serviceType: ServiceType [];
    selectedService: ServiceType; 

//methods

 loadServicesV2(){
        const params = this.getRequestParams(this.page, this.pageSize);
    this.serviceTypeV2.GetAll(params)
        .subscribe({
            next: (result: ServiceType[]) => {

               this.serviceType = result;
                this.serviceType = result.sort((a, b) => a.value - b.value);
                console.log(result);


             // this.totalItems = parseInt(result.headers.get('x-total-count'));
            },
            error: (e) => console.error(e)
        });


}

    editSaveServices() {
        this.editServiceType();
        this.formToSelectedService();

        this.serviceTypeService.update(this.selectedService, (result: ServiceType[]) => {

            this.loadServicesV2();

        })
}

  changePage($event) {
        this.page = $event;
        this.loadServicesV2();
    }


html:
 <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                        <ngb-pagination (pageChange)="changePage($event)" [(page)]="page" [boundaryLinks]="true"
                                        [collectionSize]="totalItems"  [ellipses]="true" [maxSize]="10"
                                        [pageSize]=pageSize></ngb-pagination>
                    </div>



enter image description here
enter image description here
this.serviceType = result.sort((a, b) => a.value - b.value);
notice that i tried to sort data by id in order to solve the error but the list still starts with id 10, you can find id number 1 in page 4 (see second image)
sorry once again for the lack of resources, i hope that i provided the code in an understandable way

seems like all sorting should be done server-side before the limit or take range call.

doesn't Pageable interface supports automatic Sorting ?

JpaRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository, so you've already got the sorting for free.  On your request, pass sort=numericId,asc and delete all that code where you're trying to do the sorting

Also, Spring Data JPA supports projections, so the repository can return your DTOs as well.

do you have any developed tutorials or examples to clarify your solution(repo,service,controller)? i tried putting the sort=numericId,asc as a parameter, but i got errors in the end ,
